# Get DFSR Backlog file count from Windows Server 2016 Core?

Tags: powershell, dfs-r, windows-server-core

As far as I know, there is no way to check DFSR Backlog on Windows Server 2016 Core. Command line tools like dfsrdiag or dfsradmin do not work on Core, also I don't know the way how to use DFSR Powershell module on Core.

Do you know how to diagnose DFSR on Windows 2016 Core?

Comment: [`Get-DFSRBacklog` from TechNet](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/dac62790-219d-4325-a57b-e79c2aa6b58e) - PowerShell script that uses Windows Management Instrumentation (WMI) to retrieve DFSR backlog for replication groups of the targeted server.